# Formula of sum of 4th powers of roots of a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Is there any formula or any way to find the sum of 4th powers of roots of a polynomial f(x) over real? There are formulas for the sum of cubes of roots and sum of squares of roots, but no formula for this. I have been trying to develop one but I am not able to.